# Add context meu item to all files and folders in the solution explorer using vspackage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I want to add a menu item to the context menu of all the files and folders in the solution explorer. I was able to add my menu item to the project node with this entry in the vsct file..

```
<Menu guid="guidERAPackageAlphaCmdSet" id="ERAInsightMenu" priority="0x0700" type="Context">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_CTXT_PROJECT_ADD" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>ERA Insight</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>ERA Insight</CommandName>
    </Strings>  
  </Menu>
```

I want to get this in the context menu of all files and folders in solution explorer. What is the id i should use? Is there any place where i can find the ids for all the menus in visual studio?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but hopefully this helps someone.

If you look at the top of your vsct file, you should see this:

```
  <!--This header contains the command ids for the menus provided by the shell. -->
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
```

The path will differ based on version, but you should be able to find it in a similar path to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc

This file contains a list of all of the constants and some have descriptions.

Here is an example of what could be used for the original question from the file:

```
// Common Item Node context menu
#define IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE          0x0430

// Folder Node context menu
#define IDM_VS_CTXT_FOLDERNODE        0x0431
```

Comment: I find that IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE works for me for files in the project but IDM_VS_CTXT_FOLDERNODE does not seem to be working for me for folders (my query status callback is not called at all). There might be a catch to when the IDM_VS_CTXT_FOLDERNODE context menu is used ...

Comment: I've found [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/ide-defined-commands-for-extending-project-systems?view=vs-2019) `IDM_VS_CTXT_SOLNNODE`  to adjust the solution node context menu. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can find the ID's of all the root menus (meaning it doesn't show the children of the context menus) using the trick described in this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx

to summarize, you need to add a registry key at the following location:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/<your vs version>/General`
and the key to ass is of `DWORD` type named `EnableVSIPLogging` (you have to set it to `1`)

then before right clicking to show the context menu, hold `CTRL` and `SHIFT` and you'll see a message box containing all the ID's you need