# Visual Studio 2017 create extension for Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, customization

Is it possible to code against file in the Solution Explorer such as adding to the right click menu items when clicking on a file?

Comment: Have you seen an extension that does this already?

Comment: Not yet. Just wondering where to start or if it's even possible.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. ReSharper, among other extensions, does it. I just wanted to make sure that if someone (me, for instance), posted "Yes, it is possible" as a real answer, that your first comment wouldn't be "Yes, I know that, but how?", because then you need to rewrite your question first. Are you *really* looking for a yes/no answer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467477/add-context-meu-item-to-all-files-and-folders-in-the-solution-explorer-using-vsp